# How do I insert large text that contains parentheses, brackets, and commas into a table

Tags: sql-server

I'm generating an `INSERT_INTO` statement, and one of the fields is going to hold a large chunk of `LUA`, which contains parentheses, brackets, and commas. I'm worried they're going to cause an error when that statement is going to be parsed. What's the best way to go about this? (FYI: I'm using an app internal to my company to actually execute the statement.)

Comment: So this internal app has no support for prepared statements, which would make this a non-issue?

Comment: Don't store LUA in SQL Server? Sounds like a job for Git

Comment: The only characters that need escaping in a string literal are doubling up any single quotes. There is no reason any of the characters mentioned in the title would cause a problem.

Comment: @SteveHoward It does, although the syntax for the prepared statement object just asks for the entire command as a string, so I was worried about this. I can contact the team that manages it to see if it it would be an issue, and update here.

Comment: So there is no way of using parameters then? Although for a single adhoc statement just escape any single quotes and you should be good to go anyway.

Comment: If you can't pass the LUA string as a parameter and must escape the string by doubling up the single quotes, remember that the escaped string may be longer than the original string. This could cause the LUA string to be truncated if the data types you're using don't have space to hold a string twice as long as the original "large chunk."

Comment: @SteveHoward +1 on your comment. It does support prepared statements, and that is indeed the recommended way to do this. Thanks!